# How to use "COLLECT" in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

For **COLLECT** Im getting error like
*ERROR:  syntax error at or near "COLLECT"
LINE 48:     EXECUTE W_SQL BULK COLLECT*

I have written like this

```
 EXECUTE W_SQL BULK COLLECT
      INTO STRICT current_setting('pkg_beneficiary.ifsc_fetch_obj')::IFSC_FETCH_STRING;
```

please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Where [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) did you find COLLECT?

Comment: Also `current_setting()` is for returning a value not setting it.

Comment: BULK COLLECT is used in Oracle (afaik only Oracle) to populate a collection. The closest thing in Postgres to an Oracle collection is an array.  What is the issue you are actually trying to solve.